# What happens to values on the stack that get placed in array on the Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory

I want to know if I create an array on the Heap in C++ and I assign data from the stack to the Array, what exactly happens? Is the data copied onto the heap?

code fragment:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int *c = new int(3);
int *arr = new int[3];
arr[0] = a;
arr[1] = b;
arr[2] = *c;
```

Comment: Yes they are copied. I don't get what about you're asking? `int c = new int(3);` won't compile BTW.

Comment: If you assign to variables, data is copied. It doesn't matter where those variables live.

Comment: A quick question: Can you have an array of references? i.e an Array of addresses of objects.

Comment: You can't have an array of references; you *can* have an array of pointers. And you can, if inclined, have an array of objects wrapping references.

Comment: Thank you. I was just really confused about this. I was also reading that you can't have pointers to references yet C++ has the syntax int a = 3; int *p = &a. Isn't that a pointer to a reference. I'm sure I am mistaken though because int b = &a; and then int *p = &b; Is a pointer to a reference am I correct?

Comment: @rert588 You seem to miss to understand the role of `&` when used to obtain the address of a variable vs declaring a reference variable or paramteter.

Comment: @rert588 `int *p = &a` -- There are no references in that line of code.  The `&` symbol has two distinct meanings in C++.  In this case, that is `address-of`.

Answer (score 0):

`int a = 3;`
a has the value 3.
the memory address of a is 0x345A or something like it.
a is on the stack.

`int *p = &a;`
pointer p is assigned the address of a. The memory address of p is 0x123B or something like it. That memory address holds the value 0x345A pointing to the location where the value `3` is stored. Pointer p is on the stack.

You'd get `3` if you print `a` and `*p` since they are getting their value from the same memory location.

You'd get `0x345A` if you print `&a` and `p` since a's address is the value p holds.

You'd get `0x123B` if you print `&p` since that is the memory location for pointer p.

Assuming *c points to an integer on the heap, you could store the value of c (which is the memory address of the integer on heap) in an array.

```
int *arr = new int[3];
...
arr[2] = c;
```

What you do NOT want to do is:

```
int foo = 10;
arr[2] = &foo;
```

Now, your array is pointing to a memory location that that is  on the stack. Will work OK as long as you are in that function, but will be pointing at garbage once you exit the function and stack is reclaimed.